# Restrict string to maximum 2 characters

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows
var code = S0622,Q4033
I want to restrict the length of the characters as follows
S0,Q4
Please let me know how to do this

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a valid code example and explain what you mean by "restrict the length of the characters". It's not clear if this is user input, a single string, an array, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code you provided is a `String`. Something like this could work.
You can just split with `,` and then just using native `forEach` to iterate and push your value to a new array and join that array after wards.

```
var finalCode = [];
var code = 'S0622,Q4033';
code.split(',').forEach(function(item, index){
        finalCode.push(item.substring(0,2));
    }
);
finalCode.join();
```

Comment: this worked, thank you